# Remove empty XML tags via bash/terminal

Tags: xml, bash, command-line, terminal

Is there an easy way to remove a specific set of xml tags from an xml file from within terminal?

All the tags I want to remove have a pattern of column_1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9(some number).

I want to preserve though, column_1 through column_9, and delete anything higher than that.

Comment: Can you please post an example of the XML file you want to process both before and after processing?

Comment: Is XSLT an acceptable technology for your environment? There's the command line processor `xsltproc` for Linux and Windows. Also XSLT processors in Java.

Comment: The file itself is 50 MB. The problem is, all the empty tags are causing parsers to run out of memory, even when I try to remove them with PHP or regex from command line. Each node has column_1 through column_9 with actual data in it, with 1721 nodes with data. The problem is, each row has these ambiguous empty tags from column_10 through column_1800 which are empty and a byproduct of a OpenOffice XSLX->XML conversion.

Comment: It's hard to visualize what your data looks like. Can you edit your post to include a minimal version of one node with columns 8,9,10,11,12. That will give us something to work with. Is the data one big string, or are there line-feeds helping with formatting. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO this should be sufficient:

```
sed '/^ *<column_[0-9][0-9]\+ *\/> *$/d' file.xml > reduced.xml
```

Edit:

```
cat > test.xml << EOF 
<column_1 />
<column_2 />
<column_9 />
<column_10 />
<column_1180 />
EOF

sed '/^ *<column_[0-9][0-9][0-9]* *\/> *$/d' test.xml
```

Output:

```
<column_1 />
<column_2 />
<column_9 />
```

If there are more than one occurrence in one line:

```
 echo "<column_1 /><column_2 /><column_9 /><column_10 /><column_1080 />" > test2.xml

 sed 's/<column_[0-9][0-9][0-9]* *\/>//g' test2.xml
```

Output:

```
 <column_1 /><column_2 /><column_9 />
```

Comment: are you sure about the '\' before +? It could also be done as `[0-9][0-9][0-9]*` ... Also, do we know that <colum...> is only aword on the line, allowing for padded spaces as the opening `/^ *` and closing ` *$/` mandate? Good luck to all.

Comment: @Kevin: Maybe it's a problem of escaping '+'. Try the second sed statement: `sed '/^ *<column_[0-9][0-9][0-9]* *\/> *$/d'`

Comment: @shellter: I need to escape '+' in my bash. But your [0-9][0-9][0-9]* should do the same.